# remove comma seperated string and replace it in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, prototypejs

I have a string as `str = "aa@gmail.com,pp@gmailcom,cc@gmail.com,"`
I am replacing the string with quotes like below

```
var re = new RegExp("cc@gmail.com", "g");
$('reminder_email').value= str.replace(re," ");
```

I am able to replace the email id that matches in regex.. But the comma still remains there. So the result will be like

> "aa@gmail.com,pp@gmailcom,,"

But I need to replace the email id with comma (which comes after each one).. How to do that..

Comment: why can't you split and rejoin the string barring the last element.

Comment: Add the comma to the regex? Also, it might be safer if you escape the dot in the regex.

Comment: how to add comma in regex pattern above.. I am new to regex

Comment: Haven't tested but try something like `new RegExp("cc@gmail\.com[,]+", "g");`

Comment: will it remove email with cc@gmail.com and comma at the end of that?

Comment: I am using varibale inside regex.. So cc@gmail.com wil be replaced with that variable..

Comment: I tried using this...var re = new RegExp(str1[,]+, "g"); But it showing some error

Comment: Then you have to do it like `str+ "[,]+"`. But really I guess that is too much for this particular case. You can just use the answer that Sandip has provided. Just take your variable string (say `str`) and do `new RegExp(str+"," , "g");`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NGq4t/)

```
str = "aa@gmail.com,pp@gmailcom,cc@gmail.com,"
var re = new RegExp("cc@gmail.com,", "g");
a= str.replace(re," ");
```

Comment: I am using varibale inside regex.. So cc@gmail.com wil be replaced with that variable.. 
I tried using this...var re = new RegExp(str1[,]+, "g"); But it showing some error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't know if you'll leave a dangling leading, dangling trailing or doubled comma depending on whether the removed target is first, last or in the middle respectively.

The easy way is to clean up misplaced commas after doing the first replace:

```
str.replace(re," ").replace(/,,+/, ",").replace(/^,|,$/, "");
```